# How to implement oAuth2 along with JWT authentication in spring boot?

Tags: mongodb, oauth-2.0, spring-boot, jwt, jhipster

I am creating a spring boot web app using jhipster and mongodb as primary database. Need to implement Oauth2 for authentication along with JWT token mechanism so that every request does not hit the database for authentication. How can I implement this mechanism?

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [**Where to Start**](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), then address your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB (or any database) is not particularly relevant to the JWT authentication since the JWT itself can be validated locally by the resource server using the public key of the authorization server without going to the database (as you say).

The key is using a JwtTokenStore

I found this github sample helpful: https://github.com/dsyer/spring-security-angular/tree/master/oauth2

I also created a basic jwt implementation with jhipster for you to look at. Here are the changes from what jhipster generated for me: https://github.com/sdoxsee/jwt-jhipster/commit/40090fcf4fab1b556ae28532c4ba8a33e70460c9

Comment: Wow. So nice of you. Thanks a lot for the help. I have few more queries here. Where and how the refresh_tokens are being generated and saved? If I want to add more authorities apart from user and admin, whats the proper process to achieve this?

Comment: Using new spring versions in https://github.com/mariocuellar1/oauth-server-jwt