# Spring boot REST api digest authentication with mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, rest, spring-boot, spring-security

I am fairly new to spring boot, and I developed a REST api which other applications will consume.. At the same I need to give those applications login credentials (login & password) [that are stored in a mongodb collections], by which they will login to the service.. 
Can someone direct me to a good start, tutorials etc.?

Comment: I would suggest you use oAuth2 and you caan refer this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31864288/how-to-implement-oauth2-along-with-jwt-authentication-in-spring-boot) for start

Comment: @Apollo Thanks, but that question is a bit broader than mine.. I will have a look at OAuth2 as well

Comment: All you need to generate an auth token using JWT and store it mongoDb and return it to client as well, this token need to be present in header for each subsequent call to protected APIs.
And then have a filter for each protected API so that you intercept the calls and access token from header and validate it, you can easily achieve this using spring security.

Comment: Yes we can easily use tokens. The harder part is expring, refreshing and revoking them. If client apps are browser based then see the following Spring blog article which suggests using a traditional cookie/server side session approach as a much simpler mechanism: https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii#help-how-is-my-application-going-to-scale